# Using regex in react router path prop to conditionally render components

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

There may be a better solution here than using regex, but not sure how to go about it.

The issue is that I want my navigation component that lives in a component called `MainLayout` to show on all routes except on `/login` & `/logout

Currently, I have the following 3 routes

```
<Route exact path="/logout" component={Logout} />
<Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
<Route
  exact
  path="/:subdirectory?/:nested?/:id?/"
  component={MainLayout}
/>
```

So navigating to `/login` or `/logout` will render either `Login` or `Logout` and also `MainLayout` which is understandable with the current setup.

However, is there a way to use regex (or any other means) to check that if `/:subdirectory` is either `/login` or `/logout` then do not render component?

Comment: Just [pass a prop](https://ui.dev/react-router-pass-props-to-components/) in that Route like `excludeNav` and then check for that in your MainLayout?

Comment: Why not simply using a Switch ? https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Switch